# Django assertTemplateUsed fails after redirect

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

I am working on a Django 2.1 practice project. Last line of my test keeps failing.
Is it true that assertTemplateUsed check won't work if redirection happens?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test_views.py", line 24, in test_home_page_not_login_redirect
>       self.assertTemplateUsed(resp, 'users/home.html')
>     File "testcases.py", line 554, in assertTemplateUsed
>       self.fail(msg_prefix + "No templates used to render the response")
>   AssertionError: No templates used to render the response

```
test_views.py
def test_home_page_not_login_redirect(self):
    resp = self.client.get('/')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 302)
    self.assertRedirects(resp, '/accounts/login/?next=/')
    self.assertTemplateUsed(resp, 'users/login.html')
```

```
urls.py
url(r'^login/$',
    auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
        template_name='users/login.html',
        redirect_authenticated_user=True),
    name='users_login'),
```

```
settings.py
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/login/'
```

Comment: /pedant_mode You should split your test into different tests: one that tests the redirect, and another that tests that your login view uses the template you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the reploy is a 302 FOUND redirect there's no template used for the HTTP response!

If you want to actually follow the redirect chain you can pass the `follow=True` parameter to `self.client.get` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get). This way you'll be able to actually check which template was used to render the (redirected) response.